# Which fields do I need to look for in api, to determine a bq dataset is publicly accessible?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want to generate a list of bigquery datasets that are publicly accessible. From the documentation I got to know if a role is associated with "allUsers" or "allauthenticatedUsers", we say it as publicly accessible. I was using a get-api to pull the data, not sure which field do I need to look for to grab allUsers and allauthenticatedUsers, is it "specialgroup" field ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is under the `specialGroup` field since the values here are the **Groups** that are pre-created by **GCP** and **BigQuery**.

eg.

- `projectOwners` --> All owners of the Project
- `projectWriters` --> All Editors of the Project
- `projectReaders` --> All viewers of the Project
- `allUsers` --> All users who is on the internet, including authenticated and unauthenticated users
- `allAuthenticatedUsers` --> All service accounts and all users on the internet who have authenticated with a Google Account

For more information, you may refer to this [BigQuery Primitive Roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control-basic-roles?hl=en_US#primitive_roles_for_projects) and [GCP IAM Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview).

In addition, the access of a dataset can also be validated by running the below command in **Cloud Shell** to get dataset information:

```
bq show --format=prettyjson project_id:dataset
```

**Output:**
[image]

For more information, you may refer to this [Getting dataset information](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-metadata#getting_dataset_information) documentation. It also has the snippets of code to retrieve dataset information using Client Libraries (ie. Python, Java, etc.)

Comment: Does "allUsers" also falls under specialgroup??

Comment: Yes since it is a special identifier that represents anyone who is on the internet and not a Group that we can manually control the members since this includes authenticated and unauthenticated users.